# Trying to create google map using javascript in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, pubnub

I am trying to create the google map with PubNub and angular, but the map is not displaying if I use the angular framework, but If I use directly javascript and HTML it is working.

can any one tell me wat I am doing wrong.

**HTML: app.component.html**

```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head>
     <title>Google Maps Example</title>
      <script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.19.0.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
     </head>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
     <h1>PubNub Google Maps Tutorial - Live Device Location</h1>
     <div id="map-canvas" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>
   </div>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=APIKEY&callback=initialize"></script>
  <script src="../app/app.js"></script>
 </body>
```

After this I have created Javascript file, Instead of using Typescript.

**app.js:**

```
window.lat = 37.7850;
window.lng = -122.4383;

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updatePosition);
    }

    return null;
};

function updatePosition(position) {
  if (position) {
    window.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    window.lng = position.coords.longitude;
  }
}

setInterval(function(){updatePosition(getLocation());}, 10000);

function currentLocation() {
  return {lat:window.lat, lng:window.lng};
};

var map;
var mark;

var initialize = function() {
  map  = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {center:{lat:lat,lng:lng},zoom:12});
  mark = new google.maps.Marker({position:{lat:lat, lng:lng}, map:map});
};

window.initialize = initialize;

var redraw = function(payload) {
  lat = payload.message.lat;
  lng = payload.message.lng;

  map.setCenter({lat:lat, lng:lng, alt:0});
  mark.setPosition({lat:lat, lng:lng, alt:0});
};

var pnChannel = "map2-channel";

var pubnub = new PubNub({
  publishKey:   'YOUR_PUB_KEY',
  subscribeKey: 'YOUR_SUB_KEY'
});

pubnub.subscribe({channels: [pnChannel]});
pubnub.addListener({message:redraw});

setInterval(function() {
  pubnub.publish({channel:pnChannel, message:currentLocation()});
}, 5000);
```

can anyone help me with how to solve this problem..

Comment: I would upgrade your [PubNub SDK to the latest version](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk). v4.19.0 was release on Dec 05, 2017. Latest is v4.27.6

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to the stage of the component's life-cycle where you execute your typescript code. Your code needs to be executed after the template has been rendered, because it expects the elements to exist: `document.getElementById('map-canvas')`

You can try executing the code in the `ngAfterViewInit` method of your component

Comment: but we can not add the venila javascript into the type script file..right?

Comment: you can add js into typescript, though you might need to change some syntax (like using typescript methods instead of `function`; ) i recommend creating an angular service and wrapping the operations inside the service, then you can use the service in your component class